# Android canvas: text is under the shape

Tags: java, android, canvas

I want to draw Text on Triangle I do this:

```
for(Widgets widget: wid) {
        if(widget.getTypeString().contains("Triangle")) {
            LOGGER.info(widget.getName());
            paintTriangle.setAntiAlias(true);

            seuils = JSONUtils.getSeuilAndColor(widget);
            value = JSONUtils.getValue(widget);

            int color = this.getColorSeuil();

            paintTriangle.setColor(color);
            paintTriangle.setStrokeWidth(2);
            paintTriangle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            if(canvas.getWidth() < c.x){
                a.set(150, a.y + 300);
                b.set(10, b.y + 300);
                c.set(310, c.y + 300);
                path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
            }
            path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
            path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
            path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
            canvas.drawPath(path, paintTriangle);
            canvas.drawText(widget.getName(), b.x+20, b.y-20, paintText);

            a.set(a.x + 310, a.y);
            b.set(b.x + 310, b.y);
            c.set(c.x + 310, c.y);
            path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
        }
    }
```

The widget contains some information to build this Triangle:

- When the widget contains "Triangle" in the name it draws the Triangle
- The variable "seuils" is a HashMap that contains an Integer of a threshold and its color, that means when the variable "value" is over the treshold, the variable "color" changes and in that way the color of the shape changes too.

So my problem is if I have more than one Triangle, the Text is under the first shapes but over the last.

[Text under shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoKpX.png)

I don't understand because it works with methods Rect and Circle, and I do it in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forget to create a new Path for each Triangle, there is the new code:

```
for(Widgets widget: wid) {
        if(widget.getTypeString().contains("Triangle")) {
            LOGGER.info(widget.getName());

            Path path = new Path();
            path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
            path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);

            // Lissage des lignes, meilleur rendu à l'écran
            paintTriangle.setAntiAlias(true);

            // Initialisation des paramètres
            seuils = JSONUtils.getSeuilAndColor(widget);
            value = JSONUtils.getValue(widget);

            // Récuperation de la couleur du seuil
            int color = this.getColorSeuil();
            String hexcolor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & color));

            // Colorier le triangle en fonction du dépassement du seuil
            paintTriangle.setColor(color);
            // Largeur de la bordure du triangle
            paintTriangle.setStrokeWidth(2);
            paintTriangle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            // Création triangle dynamique
            if(canvas.getWidth() < c.x){
                a.set(150, a.y + 300);
                b.set(10, b.y + 300);
                c.set(310, c.y + 300);
                path.moveTo(a.x, a.y);
            }
            path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
            path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
            path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
            path.close();
            canvas.drawPath(path, paintTriangle);
            canvas.drawText(widget.getName(), b.x+20, b.y-20, paintText);

            a.set(a.x + 310, a.y);
            b.set(b.x + 310, b.y);
            c.set(c.x + 310, c.y);
        }
    }
```